# Syntax error trying get classname from a jquery object

Tags: jquery, dictionary, syntax-error

This seems not to be the right way:

```
$(".row-fluid div").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        getClassLFT = $this.attr("class").split(" ").map(function(item) {
            return item.indexOf("lineFromTop") === -1 ? "" : item;
        });

    // following line throws the error
    $this.find("."+ getClassLFT[0]).wrapAll("<div class='clear' />");
});
```

The last line throws following error: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .`
I want to get the first (and it's the only) value in this object. How can I handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine in your codepiece. But the collection `getClassLFT` may be empty and you may need to check it before using ...

```
if(getClassLFT.length){
  $this.find("."+ getClassLFT[0]).wrapAll("<div class='clear' />");
}
else{
  // handle here...
}
```

or use [jQuery.isEmptyObject()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)

Answer (score 1):

I think there poblem with the `getClassLFT[0]`, it might be empty collection that why its giveing error..

you need to check you code to fill the collection of `getClassLFT[0]`